# Missing Cities on Autocomplete

Tags: geocoding, here-api

Using Here GeoCode API and Discover API to search city from zip.
Works sporadically.
Google Maps API never fails to show a city with just a zip.
There MUST be a way you can force HERE to show the city (or best city) for every zip.

Eg. [example of autocomplete with city missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ty3Gr.jpg)   Anyone know why zip 22102 retrieves no city.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide the full request including I tried this call and I am getting 20 results for this zip code: `https://autosuggest.search.hereapi.com/v1/autosuggest?at=47.655548,-122.303200&q=22102&apiKey=API_KEY`

Comment: Here is the CALL - https://geocode.search.hereapi.com/v1/geocode?at=37.54068,-77.43367&q=22102&apiKey=API_KEY

Comment: I see what you are saying. This zip code crosses multiple cities, did you expect to get a list of cities? Or what do you expect to get in the results when there's not just one city that's covered by a zipcode?